# Не могу поймать исключение

Tags: java, исключения

Всем привет, никак не получается создать условие ,чтобы отловить ошибку ввода в строку букв вместо цифр.

вот часть кода :

```
     String as = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"                     Введите число");
     try {
     if(as == null || as.equals(""))throw new NullException();
     int vc = Integer.parseInt(as);
     if(as.equals("dfg"))throw new NoNumberException();  //не работает  
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"                 Спасибо");  
     }
     catch (NullException a){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,a);   
     }
     catch (NoNumberException a) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,a);
     }
     finally {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"   Программа  закончена");   
     }
```

Comment: Опиши подробней в чем заключается "не получается".

Comment: Я недавно изучаю java у меня задачка на собственные исключения . Ошибку на пустую строку обработал , а вот что бы отследить ошибку на ввод не букв а чисел не могу написать условие  " if(as.equals("dfg"))throw new NoNumberException();"  эта строка должна поймать ошибку ввода в строку букв и обработать ее выкинув в окне надпись" вы ввели не число"

Comment: извиняюсь  ошибся  поймать надо ошибку  ввода букв вместо чисел.

Comment: 1) Попросите пользователя ввести число, используя JOptionPane.

2) Если пользователь ввёл число, то выведите в JOptionPane сообщение: «Спасибо!».

3) Если пользователь ничего не ввёл выведите сообщение " Вы ничего не ввели"

Comment: 4) Если пользователь ввел не цифры а буквы выведите сообщение " Вы ввели не число"

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!as.matches("\\d+")) throw new NoNumberException();  //работает
```

`!as.matches("\\d+")` вернет вам true, если пользовательский ввод содержит любые не числовые символы.

Только эту проверку нужно делать перед `Integer.parseInt(as)`

Comment: Спасибо , этот метод мне встречался , но не нашел доходчивого объяснения как он работает .

Comment: Есть вопрос , возможно ли написать условие поимки данного исключения с помощью метода " equals".

Comment: equals() сравнивает между собой два объекта. В данном случае это две конкретные строки... вы же не можете предугадать все возможные варианты пользовательского ввода и проверить все эти варианты? Следовательно, метод equals() в данном случае бесполезен. Метод matches() проверяет строку на соответствие регулярному выражению. Одно и тоже регулярное выражение может соответствовать различным строкам. Например, регулярное выражение "\\d+" соответствует строке "5464" равным образом как и строке "004801", а значит с помощью регулярных выражений можно проверять любой вариант пользовательского ввода

Comment: Понял, спасибо.